# For loop - continue if boolean condition evaluates to false

Tags: c#

I am writing a for loop with multiple if statements.

Is it possible that if the if statement (or one part of it) in the for statement evaluates to false, then the loop does not exit but the integer to iterates increments by one and continues through the loop (I need functionality like the continue; keyword).

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Collection.Count && Collection[i].Name != "Alan"; i++)
{
    // If name is not Alan, increment i and continue the loop.
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Example code would be a big help. I have no idea what you mean about "if statements evaluating to false", if that happens then the stuff inside that doesn't get executed and the loop continues as normal.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need functionality like the `continue` keyword - have you considered using the `continue` keyword, then?

**Update:** Your example code is hard to decipher the intention of.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Collection.Count && Collection[i].Name != "Alan"; i++)
{
    // If name is not Alan, increment i.
}
```

The `for` loop has three parts to it, separated by two semi-colons. The first part initializes the loop variable(s). The second part is an expression that is evaluated each time an iteration is about to start; if it is false, the loop terminates. The third part executes after each iteration.

So your loop above will exit at the first "Alan" it encounters, and also it will increment `i` every time it finishes an iteration. Finally, if there are no Alans, it will execute the last time with `i` equal to `Collection.Count`, which is one larger than the maximum valid index into the collection. So it will throw an exception for sure, as you try to access `Collection[i]` when `i` is out of range.

Maybe you want this:

```
foreach (var item in Collection.Where(i => i.Name != "Alan"))
{
    // item is not an "Alan"
}
```

You can think of the `Where` extension method as a way of filtering a collection.

If this seems obscure, you can achieve the same thing with the `continue` keyword (as you guessed):

```
foreach (var item in Collection)
{
    if (item.Name == "Alan")
        continue;

    // item is not an "Alan"
}
```

Or you can just put the code in the `if`'s block:

```
foreach (var item in Collection)
{
    if (item.Name != "Alan")
    {
        // item is not an "Alan"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm aware of the Where() method but just thought it was feasible to go about things as above but I guess that's not the right way! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ) {
    if (!condition1) {
        i++;
    }
    if (!condition2) {
        i++;
    }
    if (!condition3) {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Do you want the incrementor for finishing the for loop to be in the body of the loop?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand correctly. You have a for loop something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // do something
    if (!b1)
      i++

    // do something
}
```

Edit:

If you use continue it increments i for only once. If you use i++ in loop it increments twice obviously. If you only want to icrement on a condition, Use the for loop like this

for (int i = 0; i < 10) // and this is very similar to a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

From your sample code, I think you are searching for the name "Alan".
Is this correct?

If so, structure your loop like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Collection.Count; i++)
{
    if (Collection[i].Name == "Alan")
    {
        break;  // We found the name we wanted!
    }

    // Otherwise: Keep going to look for the name further on.
}

if (i == Collection.Count)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Alan is not found");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Alan found at position {0}", i);
}
```